# What is it called when a Java program is written to allow 3rd party modification by putting a new class name in a properties file?

Tags: java, class, overriding, external

What is it called when a Java program is written to allow 3rd party modification by putting a new (external to the program) class name in a properties file?

Let's say that the program has a class which implements Bicycles. The 3rd party wants to make changes to Bicycles but isn't given the source code. The program allows creation of a properties file which can "override" the actual names of classes which are called to implement certain functionality. For example, one could put something like:

```
Bicycles = com.thirdparty.Bicycles
```

This would cause the program to use "my" Bicycles class instead of theirs. I could then call their class, if I so desired, which would make my new class a sort of superclass of their Bicycles class.

Comment: In a general case, Bicycles classes provided by third-party apps can be incompatible with your Bicycles class, and therefore unusable by your program.

Comment: What you're probably talking about is an "extension" of program's basic functionality and it's implemented using public interfaces in Java. Your program provides some interface ("Vehicle" for example) and other programs implement it in their classes ("Bicycle", "Car", etc.). There's no need in properties for that.

Comment: Keep in mind that I don't have any source code for the original program. I've merely been told that there are some classes where I can tell the original program (program not being mine, but provided by a vendor) to use a replacement class that I have created instead of the vendor's class. The vendor created the program such that it allows this, and looks for a line like:className = com.my.replacement.class.name